# How Route UDP Traffic to Multiple Target Groups using Network Load Balancer filtering by host header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp, amazon-elb

I have a `AWS Network Load Balancer` with:

1. a listener on UDP protocol
2. a Target Group. This Target Group is associated to ECS Fargate
3. a Elastic IP
4. some addresses (i.e. `abc.def.com`, `ghi.lmn.com`, ecc.) that pointing to the Elastic IP

With this configuration all works fine! I mean if I try to connect in UDP to `abc.def.com` (and then to `ghi.lmn.com`) the ECS instance responds correctly.

Assuming that I created 2 ECSs, the next step is to configure the Network Load Balancer in this manner:

- if the request comes from `abc.def.com` then the Load Balancer route the request to target group associated to ECS1
- if the request comes from `ghi.lmn.com` then the Load Balancer route the request to target group associated to ECS2

How Can I configure the Network Load Balancer? How Route UDP Traffic to Multiple Target Groups using Network Load Balancer filtering by host header?

Comment: What you are describing is called routing by host headers, not "filtering". Unfortunately, only Application Load Balancers support this feature. You can't do this with Network Load Balancers.

Comment: A "host header" can only be part of the application payload and only some application protocols have such a header at all. Nothing in your question really suggests that your unknown UDP traffic even has such a header and how exactly it looks like. It is more like you assume that a header is a general property of traffic, which it isn't. If there is no such thing as a host header in the first place or if the load balancer does not work at the application level it is impossible to forward traffic based on this information.